# PHP get specific value of a specific key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following array (this comes from a var_dump):

```
($defaults = )array(3) {
  ["sitewide_typography_title"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["font-family"]=>
    string(16) "Playfair Display"
    ["variant"]=>
    string(7) "regular"
  }
  ["sitewide_typography_text"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["font-family"]=>
    string(6) "Roboto"
    ["variant"]=>
    string(3) "300"
  }
  ["sitewide_typography_btn"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["font-family"]=>
    string(6) "Roboto"
    ["variant"]=>
    string(3) "300"
  }
}
```

I guess this is an easy question, but I really can't find the answer. I think my googling skills failed me in this, but how do I get the `font-family` value for `sitewide_typography_title`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple

```
$defaults['sitewide_typography_title']['font-family'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To echo it out like this

`echo $defaults['sitewide_typography_title']['font-family'];`

Should output

`Playfair Display`